# How to use title with headers

Tags: php, image, gd

I am using this code:

```
<?php
   header("Content-type:image/gif");
   And some PHP gd code below to generate the image
?>
```

The problem is that the page title is set to an image of width x height. Is there a way to change the page title, without using the following?

```
<img src='link'/>
```

NOTICE: I don't need to use any JavaScript code or external file.

Comment: Could you express your question more clearly? You can change the page title dynamically using Javascript's `document.title`.

Comment: @LonelyWebCrawler the OP is changing the page's content-type through the header to an image/gif type. The browser will just try to render the gif. Javascript is not valid.

Comment: My question is clear i want to change the page title

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the image's new window in `html`. I'm assuming from the question's poor wording that you are opening a new window with "just the image" as its content?

If so, just wrap it via HTML. Unless a browser is not consuming the result, in which case you need to be more specific to the process / purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The text you see in the title of a page like this is determined by the browser. You can't change it via PHP. When rendering an HTML page, the browser looks for the `title` element, however, in everything else, it chooses the title based on attributes of the page you're viewing. As you guessed it, the only alternative is to create an HTML page and reference the image through an `img` tag and changing the title through the `title` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an html page, with an iframe (size = 100%), that embeds the image. Then you can then set the title in the HTML page.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>YOUR TITLE</title>
<style type="text/css">
        html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
        iframe {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;
            border: none; padding-top: 32px;
            box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://www.nbc.com/"></iframe>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you understanding what he's doing? He wants to use the GD Library but doesn't like the fact that he can't change the title of content that's sent to the browser as `image/png`. No html will render in a `.png` content-type.

Comment: @Nile He said: `the page title is set to an image of width x height. Is there a way to change the page title`. So I assumed he meant the small icon that is displayed next to the page title. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes, look at the code he said he was using. He's using the GD library so the browser is processing his page as an image/gif.

Comment: The code shows the `Content-type` not the `title`. Maybe he just didn't use the correct term ? Using GD, the image you serve (for download) will have `Content-type:image/gif` but it doesn't mean that the whole page should have `Content-type:image/gif`.

Comment: Adding `header("Content-type: image/gif")` to your page makes the page render to the browser as an image, so yet... it does mean that.

Comment: @Nile In that case I'll change my answer.

Comment: He doesn't want to use HTML though (implied by "without using the following? [img code here]". that's why what he wants to do is impossible. Document titles aren't set by page headers, there set by markup.

Comment: @Nile since I didn't use neither `img` nor `JS` - then, technically, this answer is correct ;)

Comment: I won't delete my answer, in case he regrets and decides to use it.